# zError on my iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, instruments

I am optimizing my app which run a little bit too slow on an iphone 4.

This app uses openGL ES 2.0 and a lot of textures, these textures are twice larger on retina screens.

After a check in instrument I found this function which use 5.9% of the CPU :
zError (from libz.1.dylib)
this function is called by 3 methods:

- png_read_row
- inflate
- png_inflate

Do you know which problem can cause this error ?